# Eager loading fetches all fields though select is explicitly specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, eager-loading

I have a query like this,

```
company.users.select("users.id, users.state").includes(:organization)
```

here I'm eager loading the association `organization`. I was expecting the attributes id and user_id to be fetched in the objects, but then I get all fields fetched.

Is this the way, rails behaves when we eager load or am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you will get all company **users** not organizations.

Eager loading means pre-loading the database rows. It will not fetch only attributes. It loads all rows associated.

For example:

```
 comments = Comment.all(:select => "users.name,comment_text", :include => :user)
```

Here, it will not just load names from user table. It will get all users rows from the database. So you don't have to fire extra queries. And one more thing is when you use `include` select clause is ignored when you have attributes of included tables. For more info go through ryan bates rialscast on joins vs include : http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins

Comment: In the above query, if comments table has 20 records and 10 columns, it loads all of them, but if I need only, 2 columns in those 20 records, how do I do that ??  with the query I mentioned, I wasnt able to do

Comment: @ManjunathManohar Sorry sorry.

Comment: @ManjunathManohar cross checked. select clause is ignored when you use eager load. If you use join select will work.

Comment: @ManjunathManohar In your case why are you eager loading `organizations` when you only need `id and user_id`. Is `id and user_id` belong to organization. Can you explain what is `id and user_id`

Comment: id and user_id are the columns in the company table

Comment: Then why are you doing company.users just use company.id and company.user_id

Comment: actually sorry, it was just an example. My intention is  to just select the attributes and also include an association

Comment: You can use select to get columns which are belongs to included tables. For example: Company.last(:select => "id, company_name", :include => :users). If you add included table(s) column(s) in select it will simply ignore select and gives all fields of company. For ex: Company.last(:select => "id, company_name, users.name", :include => :users). Eager load is just used to avoid multiple query fired to database.